# Call method based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 methods that I would like to put into a list and call dynamically (through another method) based on another variable's value. Unsure if that's possible, but this is what I'm attempting and the error I'm receiving is: 'str' object is not callable. I know that the methods listed are strings, but is there a way to do this or is this approach just not functional?

```
def CallMethod(self):

   Method_List = [
      'Method_1',
      'Method_2',
      'Method_3',
      'Method_4'
       ]

   self.base_index == 1

   self.MethodType = Method_List[self.base_index]
   
   result = Table([self.MainBodyType()])
```

Comment: The good thing with software is, that you can simply try things yourself at (almost) no cost. Why do you have strings in the list and not methods? As you do not show your code we cannot see how your methods are defined, what they are called, etc.

Comment: when I try to put them in as Method_1(), Method_2(), etc. there is an "undefined name" error. Does this def need to occur after the methods are defined?

Comment: `Method_1()` is a call of the method, which will try to put the return value of `Method_1` in the list. Your method is (most likely) called `Method_1` not `Method_1()`.

Comment: That's because the method names aren't global variables; they are *class* attributes. You want to store the bound methods `self.Method_1`, et al. in the list, then call `Method_List[self.base_index](...)`.

Comment: @chepner can you post this as the answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method names aren't global; they are *class* attributes.

Instead of storing the attribute name as a string, store the bound method you want to call directly in the list.

```
def CallMethod(self):

   Method_List = [
      self.Method_1,
      self.Method_2,
      self.Method_3,
      self.Method_4
       ]

   base_index = 1

   result = Method_List[base_index]()

   ...
```